# Boundary of a general plane domain?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, plane-curves

Is it trivially true that the boundary $\partial U$ of a *domain* $U\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is a finite (or countable?) union of disjoint Jordan curves?

Comment: Numerable? Do you mean countable? Also does *domain* mean something like open and connected or some similar construct? And *collection* should mean union? Or is it not allowed for the jordan curves to intersect each other (or themselves)?

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, I stressed that it's a domain (open, connected and non-empty). I'll edit my post.

Comment: The boundary of a domain can be very complicated. It can have uncountably many connected components, it can have positive (two-dimensional) measure (but this can also happen when the boundary is a Jordan curve), it can be connected but not path-connected … Every closed set with empty interior is the boundary of an open set. Requiring the open set to be connected adds some restrictions (for example you can't have three "nested" circles), but it hardly restricts the possible wildness of the boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true (let alone trivially true). Consider $U = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Then $\partial U = \{(0,0)\}$, which is not a union of Jordan curves (because a Jordan curve is always infinite...).

Comment: This is only a counterexample when he disallows intersecting Jordan curves.

Comment: @M.Winter I am not sure I follow. Can you write $X$ as a union (even an intersecting one) of Jordan curves?

Comment: Thanks for answering! So we can only say that the boundary of domain is a union of curves (not necessary Jordan curves)?

Comment: @Hulkster I just found an even simpler example. Please see my edit.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Probably I am wrong. I thought a Jordan curve must not necesarily be closed. But the internet says otherwise.

Comment: @Hulkster Though to be fair it depends on what you mean by curve. An immersion of $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Just continuous curves in $\mathbb{R^2}$  :)

Comment: @Hulkster Well then, you can take as a curve a constant curve, and its image is a singleton. And every set is a union of singletons.

Answer (score 2):

The boundary of the following shape is self-intersecting, hence no Jordan-curve.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: Hmm. Since that is a domain, i.e. it has no boundary, then the boundaty is a single Jordan curve?

Comment: @Hulkster I am not sure if I understood you correctly. The shape has a boundary. It is just not part of the domain (which is true for all domains). A Jordan-curve is not allowed to intersect itself, hence the boundary is no Jordan-curve.

Comment: But since that domain is *open*, then there is enough room for that boundary curve not to intersect itself.

Comment: I see your confusion. The both "touching" arms of the above shape are of distance zero from each other. This is possible while still being open. Look for example at two open discs of radius $r=1$, one with center $(0,1)$ and the other with center $(0,-1)$. I know they are not connected, but the idea is the same as in my post. The boundary of both discs contains the point $(0,0)$, but no disc contains this point. Hence, the boundaries are connected, while the discs are not.